# How to add new node in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

I am trying to add new node in Jenkins. I want to know that new node machine or slave pc should have jenkins in it or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No,
only additional sw, like a git, etc..

Then simply go to `<JenkinsURL>/computer/createItem` make an configuration and select launch option

Refer to (link updated due comment) https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows

Just for windows you will need .net framework probably

Comment: It should be probably enough to have Java installed for start new slave :D

Comment: Updated link - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows

Answer (score 0):

You Can refer to https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows which shows how to setup slave for jenkins

Comment: Updated link - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows